# Ubuntu 18.04 Dash file search equivalent?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, search, ubuntu-mate

In Ubuntu 16.04, <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> brings the dash file search where one can quickly find a file by its name. Very convenient, I use it all the time.

Is there an equivalent in either the GNOME flavour or the MATE flavour of Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In GNOME in Ubuntu 18.04, you will find files by name by typing part of the name in the search box in the dash. This, without the need to have the GNOME file indexing service, tracker, installed, which is not installed in Ubuntu by default. "Files" must be checked under "Search" under "Settings".

In Ubuntu 17.10, a search in the dash would not bring up files.

MATE standard has no such build-in feature, but a dedicated search panel plugin may be available.

Alternatively, you may want to consider a dedicated quick-launcher. The [Albert launcher](https://github.com/albertlauncher/albert) is very good in what you are seeking, finding files by name to launch them. You could assign it the shortcut <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>. Other launcher may also do well, but personally, I did not find one that performs like Albert for this task.

Comment: I use Albert as my main launcher. For other interested users: it is not in the Ubuntu PPA's. You can install it here: https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home:manuelschneid3r&package=albert Click on the Ubuntu logo and you will see instructions on how to add the PPA, or have the opportunity to download the .deb for installation.

Comment: I have "Files" checked in Settings -> Search, and none of the files in a `/c/` path, which I open regularly with LibreOffice, show up.